# Pasar datos de datagridview en un UserControl a textbox en otro userControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buenas noches a todos.

Tengo un problema al pasar datos de un DataGridView a TextBox, ver si me pueden ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   private void btnEntrarManzana_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatosParaActualizarEventArgs.TextoDeEjemplo = dgvManzana.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        DatosParaActualizarEventArgs.MontoDeEjemplo = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvManzana.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        DatosParaActualizarEventArgs.cambiar = true;
    }
```

tengo una clase:

```
public static class DatosParaActualizarEventArgs
{

    public static string TextoDeEjemplo { get; set; }
    public static decimal MontoDeEjemplo { get; set; }
    public static bool cambiar { get; set; }
}
```

Este el UserControl que quiero pasar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el Formulario, al dar click al botón Pasar, este lo que hace es que pasa los mismo dato de la columna a la fila más abajo vacía.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el ejemplo de la aplicación:

https://mega.nz/file/VV8DxQLD#RqKjeTKQAja5b1DBCWvazbqixKQZORbrlXsk9yvDIL4

Comment: y cual es el problema? porque tu pregunta no dice absolutamente nada de ningun problema...

Comment: Y cual es el problema_

Comment: Hola, el problema esta al pasar los datos del datagridview a los textbox. Al seleccionar la fila y al dar click en el boton este me carga otra linea del mismo datagridview. lo que quiero es pasar los datos a los textbox

Comment: Que fila te carga? el codigo debe estar todo en la pagina, no hay que ir a buscarlo a un servicio externo. si carga otra fila, verificaste que no cambie la seleccion? porque estas usando currentrow en lugar de selectedrow...

Comment: Pondre una imagen, lo que busco es poder editar los datos que paso al Datagridview , al dar click en el boton lo que me hace es agregar una fila mas al Datagridview y no a los Textbox